# How to set effect or transition at setCutPlaneSet?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a possible way to set the effect or transition to see smoothly while setting the cut plane?

```
// Select floor 2
const CutPlaneSetName = 'Autodesk.AEC.FloorSelector';
let floorIndex = 2;
floorExtension.floorSelector.selectFloor(floorIndex);

// Capture roof floor 2 
const cuts2 = myviewer.impl.getCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName);

// Select floor 1
floorIndex = 1;
floorExtension.floorSelector.selectFloor(floorIndex);

// Capture roof floor 1 
const cuts1 = myviewer.impl.getCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName);

// Restore roof floor 2
const planes = [ cuts1[0], cuts2[1] ];
myviewer.impl.setCutPlaneSet(CutPlaneSetName, planes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually activate some animation using the FloorRenderMode enum, but this is when using the UI.

```
const FloorRenderMode = {
    // mouse is hovering over a floor button
    Hovering:   0,
    // new floor has been selected and anim is running
    Transition: 1,
    // default rendering
    Off:        2
};
```

You probably want to use the transition effect instead when selecting floors.

```
floorExtension.floorSelector.selectFloor(floorIndex, true);
```